# MongoDB connection error: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to connect to my DB. When I hit `npm start` in my cli, this error pops up...

I've looked online for similar issues but people have one line of code similar to this one:

```js
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@db:27017/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

In my case, I only have an `.env` file with my logs. I've tried to put this inside my server.js file but it didn't work.

here's the error :

```sh
MongoDB connection error: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
    at parseConnectionString (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:565:21)
    at connect (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:282:3)
    at /home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:223:5
    at maybePromise (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:662:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:219:10)
    at /home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:791:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:788:19)
    at /home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:342:10
    at /home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mathieu/projects/techproject/shopster/models/ProductModel.js:4:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10) {
  name: 'MongoParseError'
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide the code you have that has the connection string so we can help. We can't see what's wrong with your string without seeing how you used it. Of course use fake data for user/password and address

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check which version of Mongoose you are using?

If you're using version `v.6` or above, you no longer needed to specify `useNewUrlParser: true`.

**Mongoose 6** always behaves as if it's true, therefore this option is not required. Once you remove that option, your code should work fine.

References:

- [Migrating to 6.x](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options)

Comment: Answers to a question should not include questions that need clarification from the answer. See [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).